# Audit Fail on Possibly Correct Answer to Obviously Poor Question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I'm interested in understanding the motivation for this audit. The question seems poor. I personally don't know anything about facebook, or how convoluted the question is, but the answer is clearly attempting to address some aspect of the question.

Frequently, if an answer seems thin, or too simple, and is in a coding language or platform I'm not especially familiar with, then I'll skip it. I suppose I could have just skipped this. But when I look at the accepted answer for this question, I still wonder whether this is a good candidate for audit.

[image]

Original Question:
[How to create commercial Facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774701/how-to-create-commercial-facebook-page/49404188#49404188)
[image]

Comment: You sure that link actually goes to Facebook?

Comment: Also...what value would this answer have for development purposes?  What question was it attached to?

Comment: will update with the question it's answering

Comment: Ah, the link could have been bad. Never occurred to me to check.

Comment: Yep - the link is bogus.  This makes this a spam answer and should be nuked from high orbit.  The question probably shouldn't be left around, either...

Comment: Lesson learned : When reviewing, always check all the links in an answer... you never know...

Comment: That answer reeks to high heaven and suggests it's an answer to an off topic question.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of this question. It was an answer to an obviously poor and off-topic question, but how one should handle auditing the answer for a poor or off-topic question. As the audit was for the answer not the question. If someone posts "what is 1 plus 1" and you are asked to review the answer of "1 plus 1 is 2: [link to how math works]" what do you do? This was sidetracked by a hidden link being spam, but you get the point.

Comment: The "for the purpose of this introduction" part should be a dead giveaway that this is not an answer specific to the question, and is plagiarism at best, spam at worst...either way I think it's a fair audit.

Comment: The second paragraph being copy and pasted was never in question.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's clever spam, but still spam. Here's the markdown for the post:

```
To get started building your own Facebook Page, go [https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/.][1]

There, you’ll have six different categories to choose from:

    Local Business or Place
    Company, Organization or Institution
    Brand or Product
    Artist, Band or Public Figure
    Entertainment
    Cause or Community
Depending on which option you select, the about fields on your Page will be customized. For the purpose of this introduction, let’s say we’re a “Company, Organization or Institution.” We’ll create a Page for a (completely fictitious) company called Boston Coat Company. Choose the name for your Page wisely. Facebook will let you change your name and URL in most cases, but it can be a difficult and tedious process.


  [1]: http://prepareforjob.in/Facebook-Marketing/General-Interview-Questions/3624/q.html
```

where you can see that they took the link and surrounded it with a link to their spam site.

It was flagged as spam and deleted by a moderator, causing it to be used as an audit. We do occasionally see people trying to pull this stunt on here, so it does seem to be a viable spam example to test against. When this came up in review, you should have seen a warning that this post was possibly spam and that it should be reviewed carefully. Mousing over links is something I do in cases like this.

Now, this brings up an interesting question: should the editor prevent you from submitting posts that surround text of a link with another link? Is there any viable use case for that?

In any case, I've deleted the whole question because it doesn't belong here. Took care of the spammer, too.

Comment: [How about a word with the other person that said that this "Looks OK"?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19264809)  (Oh, a use case for having the text of a link not mesh with the actual link.  But you do have a valid point.  More discussion/thought on what that system would look like is needed.)

Comment: *Now, this brings up an interesting question: should the editor prevent you from submitting posts that surround text of a link with another link? Is there any viable use case for that?* - Maybe making the visible link shorter than the actual URL if it contains a bunch of parameters? I don't think I've actually seen a legit version of that in the wild.

Comment: I understand now. Need to make mousing over links part of my review process. Though some neat system that showed both the link and the link text at the same time, while reviewing, would be useful. The callout for why the answer was flagged covered every possible option, so hadn't pointed directly to spam.

Comment: I've edited out the link to the spammers site, no need to give them any Google link credit :)

Comment: @DavidG I had always assumed that a URL that's present as plain text (rather than as the `href` of an `<a>` element or perhaps in some other way marked up as a link) wasn't treated as a link by Google; after all, Google treating such non-link links as links would kind of destroy the usefulness of `rel="nofollow"` as an anti-spam deterrent. Do you have evidence that I'm wrong?

Comment: @DavidG Aha, it's more nuanced than what either of us thought; according to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86479/49521, Google follows plain text links when trying to find new content to index, but *doesn't* take them into account when calculating Page Rank. Given that, I think it's harmless for us to let the real link be visible here, and that we should do so, so I'm gonna revert your edit. Naturally, feel free to re-revert and argue if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarkAmery But what benefit is there to having the real link there? The only thing that might happen is that page gets more traffic. Also, while it may not affect PageRank, it could add more of their content to the Google index.

Comment: @DavidG *"what benefit is there to having the real link there?"* -  we get a real example of what kind of domains and pages spammers link to, and nobody is confused about whether the real post was *actually* linking to http://horrible-spam-site.com (which, to my great disappointment, is not a registered domain). Not huge benefits, sure, but still benefits, I think.

Comment: @MarkAmery Why is a real example helpful? And anyone who is confused that wasn't the real link needs a good hard look at themselves in the mirror! Anyway, brb, off to register the domain horrible-spam-site.com...

Comment: @DavidG - I debated redacting the link when I posted this, and decided to leave the text as it was to illustrate the kind of links you might see. I doubt that leaving the quoted text in there will move the needle much on their PageRank. I like to have concrete examples when discussing the kinds of spam to be on the lookout for. I'll trade off a little exposure for any help this can provide in identifying future spam.

Comment: Yay, I get to do an experiment. [Sadly, google hasn't parsed this page yet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22That%27s+clever+spam%2C+but+still+spam.+Here%27s+the+markdown+for+the+post%22+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @BSMP but surely instead of saying "on _https://www.google.co.uk/search?[many-params]_ it says _stuff_" it makes more sense to say "[_google_](https://google.com) says _stuff_" in that case?

Comment: @Baldrickk Oh absolutely. I always prefer using the title/name as the link text if I'm not just going to copy/paste the URL. It's just the only non-malicious reason I could think of to have the visible URL for the link not match the actual link.

Comment: There used to be really good reasons for having the link-like text of the link and the link not match. I can't recall any cases that still exist though. In any case, an obvious lemma is link must go to same server.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "prevent you from submitting posts that surround text of a link with another link" is surprisingly tricky. SmokeDetector [currently has a reason that catches these](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/139), and even if you leave aside false positives from people using filenames that are actually valid links (e.g. .zip is a valid TLD) it still performs poorly.

Comment: @Vega - That looks more like a signature, and edits and a warning are usually sufficient there. If they continued, then that starts trending into spam territory. People are used to other forums, where they get away with signatures like this, and we sometimes just need to nudge them in the right direction with these.

Answer (score 30):

Leaving aside the fact that [the answer is spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366100/1709587), it's also plagiarised from https://www.hubspot.com/facebook-marketing. I had a hunch it was plagiarised after reading the very first sentence, and Googling for `"to get started building your own facebook page"` confirmed it. The following things in the post are subtle or not-so-subtle plagiarism tells:

- The first sentence explicitly states the task to be completed (*"building your own Facebook page"*). This is unusual in Stack Overflow answers; if the question is *"How do I do X?"*, answers usually don't take the form *"To do X, do Y."* Instead, they usually just jump straight in with *"Do Y."* On the other hand, it's normal for documentation or tutorials to begin by stating the task (since there's no accompanying *question* indicating what the task is). Thus this hints that the content was copied from official documentation or a tutorial.
- The term "getting started" frequently appears in tutorials but rarely in Stack Overflow answers, which hints that this content was copied from a tutorial.
- The phrase *"for the purpose of this introduction"* appears, which is a massive tell that this has been copied from a tutorial.
- Everything about the tone feels slightly *off* from what's normal on Stack Overflow. It's flowery where a typical Stack Overflow answer would be terse. For example:

  - *"your own Facebook page"* could just as well be written as *"a Facebook page"*.
  - *"There, you’ll have six different categories to choose from:"* could just as well be written as *"You'll have to pick one of these categories:"* or even just *"There are six categories:"*.
  - *"(completely fictitious)"* could just as well be written as *"(fictitious)"* or *"fictitious"* or just omitted completely.

  The whole writing style smells of a writer trying to make their writing look sophisticated, in contrast to answerers here who are typically less self-conscious and just focus on getting to the point as quickly as possible. In my experience this kind of long-winded prose is typical of bloggers and third-party tutorial sites.
- The answer instructs the reader to go to a page, then describes what content they should expect to see there and describes the fictitious company we're apparently going to create a page for, and then... stops. It's clearly incomplete; there *must* be more steps after this for the prose so far to make sense. (And there are - at https://www.hubspot.com/facebook-marketing.) This is a clear tell that the answerer has copied and pasted what he thinks is a relevant snippet of prose from an external source without actually understanding it.

You should have been able to pick up on at least *some* of these warning signs and realize that this was plagiarised content, even without noticing the spam link in there. As such, whether or not this question should've been an audit, I think this was at least an instructive example.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters if a user copy and pastes relevant information from the documentation of a language or platform as an answer. I see that pattern commonly, though I'd prefer they made it clear that it's been copy and pasted. The link being spam I think is the clear problem here.

Comment: @CHBuckingham Prose (or large blocks or code) being copied and pasted without any indication of the original source *always* justifies a mod flag. The [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) actually go further than that and dictate that quote formatting should be used to clearly distinguish copied content from the poster's own words, but I'm generally lenient and just edit in quote formatting myself in cases where the poster has provided a link to their source but not formatted their quotations properly. But unmitigated plagiarism like this? Flag 'em, every time.

Comment: Had the same feeling after reading the first few words of the answer. I would have flagged it for plagiarism, might not even have noticed the bogus link.