# Can we block or otherwise indicate a link whose destination differs from the text?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, editor, external-links

I read with interest this question about an audit fail:

[Audit Fail on Possibly Correct Answer to Obviously Poor Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366097/audit-fail-on-possibly-correct-answer-to-obviously-poor-question)

The issue was a link where the text read like a Facebook URL, but the actual URL was to a completely different site.

I think it would be a nifty SO feature to recognize link text that *looks* like a valid URL but is different from the *actual* URL and...do something with it.  Maybe put a "suspicious link" highlight on it, or show the actual URL without having to hover over it, or something.  Maybe show the user a stern warning as they write?  Suggestions are welcome.  I feel like identifying text that *could be* a valid URL would be reasonably easy to do without generating too many false positives.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think this would be useful? In my mind, it wouldn't- Ideally, everyone should be checking the text link by hovering before they click links anyway. It's just safer that way. I'm not really seeing the point of coding for this case, but you might have a valid reason why you think it's useful, so I'm inclined to believe you do. I just don't see it at the moment.

Comment: @Kendra, while in principle I agree with you, I also fail to imagine a benign scenario where text of an anchor is a URL and it doesn't match  the actual `href` attribute of that anchor. Although it could that I'm not very imaginative.

Comment: @yivi Oh, I can't imagine a use case for that either. Hence why I'm cool with giving a chance for justification... Just as the question sits, I don't see the use to the feature. My mind can definitely be changed. :)

Comment: @Ryan, it's true that your question could use with some work. If it's a feature-request, do try to explain clearly what the feature is, what it entails, what would be the payback, etc. The title of the question is confusing and doesn't completely match the body of your post. And you do not clearly define what the feature would be.

Comment: The example isn't really a good one, unfortunately. *"To get started building your own Facebook Page"* should reek of off topic question, and the person undergoing the review should open it in a new tab to review the entire context. Failure to do that is a decent review audit. As review audits go.

Comment: I see where you're going with this, as a feature request following on from the question in [my answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366100/19679) about if there were any legitimate uses of this. Nobody's been able to suggest one so far. As far as identification goes, the editor currently automatically converts links that you place in your text, so the detection is in place for something like this. In fact, that's part of what caused the confusion in that audit, because it was assumed that the editor had converted that link, not the spammer.

Comment: What counts as a URL? Is "[asp.net](https://www.asp.net/)" a URL?

Comment: I'm now reminded of all my answers on meta covering the subject of formatting links, some of which warn against malicious users hiding spam or other bad-faith links behind misleading labels. Someone once managed to [trick a *moderator*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287259/why-was-this-spam-flag-declined/287280#287280) this way.

Comment: @Laurel: Presumably, whatever the editor already considers a URL and turns into a clickable link.

Comment: I think the biggest benefit here is to make SO yet again a little less attractive to spammers/scammers/fishers etc. If the benefits outweigh the costs I honestly don't know. The amount of times such a hidden link surfaces might be very limited, and direct effects on SO would be limited as well, however it could have tremendous effects on a single unsuspecting user...

Comment: FWIW, SmokeDetector and FireAlarm have been monitoring these for over a year, and [the *vast* majority](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/139) of misleading links such as this are trivial copy/paste errors or typos.

Comment: Lemme guess - you got rick-rolled on SO?

Answer (score 9):

The post already had a warning that it was "identified... as possible spam". The problem was that it wasn't clear what exactly made the post spam just by looking at it.

It was only when viewing the markdown that it was super obvious.

I suggest we add a markdown view to the First Posts and Late Answer queues, like this:

> [image]

In the Suggested Edits queue, you are shown the markdown view by default when the [suggested edit changes a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207237/323179). Likewise, I think that if the post is "possible spam" and includes links, markdown should be the default view.

It's not enough to be able to edit to see the markdown, since clicking edit makes you [fail if it's an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283179/6083675). Having a markdown tab is likely to prevent people from needlessly failing audits when they just want to see the markdown.

In addition to this, I could see this helping to fix other problems we've had in the past, such as spam links in punctuation[...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320786/6083675)

Comment: Sure this would help in the first posts queue, but it does nothing for the unsuspecting users who stumble upon posts naturally. Who do you think is more likely to verify the veracity of the link before clicking on it?

Answer (score 7):

The community built [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) finds these posts, in fact that post was caught and spam flagged by multiple community members.

https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/111025

You can hover the ticks to see the user flagging the post and at the bottom you have the reason why it was caught

> Post - Domain prepareforjob.in indicated by possible misleading text facebook.com.

## Should SE implement this and stop these post?

I'm not so sure this is good idea, would that not only help spammers to be more effective?, don't we just help them to make a spam post that is less spammy?

What I'm saying is that we are basically creating this way an interface for user that is determined to spam, showing them what they should avoid otherwise it will be detected.

Instead, probably sooner or later SE should leverage the work of Charcoal in general.

## Should SE implement an indication in review that link is misleading?

SE had a banner on top of that post in review, I personally think it is enough, as Brad [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson)

> you should have seen a warning that this post was possibly spam and that it should be reviewed carefully.

---

Can review interface in general be improved, sure [Laurel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel) has a good [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366256/5292302) but I will keep my answer strictly to your request, hence if it should be blocked or clearly indicated in review queue.

Thanks [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) and keep up your excellent work.